# Why i get these errors when i "kill" the program while its runing?

Tags: python

**This is my code**

```
from tkinter import *
import random 
import time


def create_circles():
    for i in range(10):
        x0 = random.randint(50, 550)  
        y0 = random.randint(50, 550)
        i=40
        colors = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green", "violet", "black"]

        for o in range(5):
            
            canvas.delete('circle')
            x0 = x0 + 10
            y0 = y0 + 10
            x1 = x0 + i
            y1 = y0 + i
            canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=random.choice(colors), tag="circle")
            canvas.pack()
            i=i+8
            
            canvas.update() # Here you need to update the canvas for the new circle to show
            time.sleep(0.1) # Here you can put a delay between the appearence of the individual circles
            
      
colors = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green", "violet", "black"]
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Random balls")
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = 600, height = 600, bg = "white")
canvas.pack()
master = Canvas(tk, width = 600, height = 600, bg = "white")
master.pack()
b=Button(master, text="Quit", command=canvas.destroy).pack()  
tk.after(1000, create_circles)
tk.mainloop()
```

**And these are the errors i get when i "kil the program while its running"**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\vitya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\vitya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\balls.py", line 15, in create_circles
    canvas.delete('circle')
  File "C:\Users\vitya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2852, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

I tried it with a break function too and get the same errors, when i "kill" the program by myself, i also get the same result, but when i "kill the program after it finished draw the circles, it doesnt print any errors"
What should i do to not get this error even if i closed the window while the program is running

Answer (score 0):

The program tries to continue to draw circles even after you kill the program. And as there is no tkinter window to draw in, it produces the following error.

Make something like this to prevent the error.

```
from tkinter import *

def exit_program(event):
    if event.char == "e":
        win.quit()
        win.destroy()

win = Tk()

win.bind("<Key>", exit_program)
win.mainloop()
```

So the program exits without errors when you press `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

- Comment out line 20
- Add `exit_program()` function in line 27
- In line 37, in `Button` widget, added  `command=exit_program`

Run this and you will not getting an error when closing.

```
from tkinter import *
import random 
import time


def create_circles():
    for i in range(10):
        x0 = random.randint(50, 550)  
        y0 = random.randint(50, 550)
        i=40
        colors = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green", "violet", "black"]

        for o in range(5):
            
            canvas.delete('circle')
            x0 = x0 + 10
            y0 = y0 + 10
            x1 = x0 + i
            y1 = y0 + i
            canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=random.choice(colors), tag="circle")
            #canvas.pack()
            i=i+8
            
            canvas.update() # Here you need to update the canvas for the new circle to show
            time.sleep(0.1) # Here you can put a delay between the appearence of the individual circles

def exit_program():    
    tk.destroy()             
      
colors = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green", "violet", "black"]
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Random balls")
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = 600, height = 600, bg = "white")
canvas.pack()
master = Canvas(tk, width = 600, height = 600, bg = "white")
master.pack()
b=Button(master, text="Quit", command=exit_program).pack()  
tk.after(1000, create_circles)
tk.mainloop()
```